# I am a Nigerian citizen with ILR in the UK. Do I need a visa to go on vacation to Jamaica?

Tags: visas, nigerian-citizens, uk-residents, jamaica

I am a Nigerian citizen with ILR in the UK. Do I need a visa to go on vacation to Jamaica?